# During the Christmas concert, why does Sam look so miserable?

Tags: love-actually

Near the end of Love Actually, Sam is performing on the drums behind his love interest, Joanna.

When Joanna sings "All I want for Christmas is You" she turns and points at Sam.
[image]

To which you see his delight.
[image]

But she then points off into the crowd, and he looks miserable.
[image]

So why? Maybe I can't read body language, but I'd be pretty happy.

Answer (score 6):

He has a crush on her. Picture the scene.

> Oh, I just want you for my own
>   More than you could ever know
>   Make my wish come true
>   Baby all I want
>   for Christmas...

At the climax of the song, she turns to him, points and sings

> is You, You baby!

His little heart is complete. She wants him too! Then, sadly, she turns and points at everybody and sings about how she wants them all too ("and you", "and you", "and you"). The little soul is both devastated and frustrated. "Women" he's thinking. Poor soul. You can watch his devastation again and again if you wish:

**Conclusion:**

He only learned how to play the drums to impress her and is left unhappy at this *apparent rejection*. Of course, he later gets a kiss on the cheek so all is well (although he could have *tried to smile* at least):

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, Andrew! I was writing mine at the same time you were writing yours. (I gave yours an up-vote, since we both said basically the same thing.)

Comment: haha, I'd rather not - I watched it enough times trying to grab the screenshots for my question.

Comment: @tombull89: No worries. To cut a long story short, he fancies her, thinks that's "his" moment, then realises she's acting up for the camera - although when he goes to see her later, he gets a kiss on the cheek showing she did like him (in some way at least)

Comment: I've seen this movie a dozen times at least. (My wife loves it, and, well, it's a sweet movie!) I came up with the opinion that during Joanna's performance, she wanted to tell Sam she liked him, and that's why she pointed at him. But she was shy, so she also pointed at other people in the audience. (Poor Sam!) But I have noticed she didn't flirt with or point at anyone else on the stage, just random faceless strangers out in the audience.

Comment: @BrettFromLA: That was my interpretation. I think little Sam just started sulking earlier. If he'd kept smiling, he'd have gotten a kiss on the lips at the airport instead of a lousy cheek peck :P

Comment: True ... but he seemed pretty happy about that "lousy" cheek peck!!! XD

Answer (score 5):

Sam wants to be her one and only. She sings, "All I want for Christmas ... is you!" and she points at HIM. That makes him happy! She didn't point at anyone else, she pointed at HIM!  He didn't even think she knew his name!

But then, she starts pointing at other people too. "And you, and you, and you...." Sam suddenly thinks she was just pointing at random people. He thinks she DOESN'T want him for Christmas. She's just doing heartless choreography. So he's sad again.